# Messagebox is class or object?

Tags: c#

I am in the beginners level to learn C#. Normally in C++ if we need to access the methods/values of the class we have to declare an object instance and thru object only we can access the method. But in C#.Net I came to know for static public class we dont need to declare the object, directly we can call the method using class.method() name. Could you pls clarify me when we refer the standard class library classes, such as messagebox.

System.Windows.MessageBox.ToShow()

System.Windows - Its name space.
ToShow         - Its Method
MessageBox     - Messagebox is class or object here?

I beleive for all the standard .NET class library namespaces internally create the object instances thru constructors when we refer any of the method belongs to the class. Its always object name is same as class name as its created by constructor. pls correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Thanks,
Karikalan

Comment: Try `var msgbox = new System.Windows.MessageBox();`  Something you can do with *normally* do with classes.  Read the error message.  If you'd conclude, "hey, that's not much of a real class" then you're quite right.  It's a bag of methods.

Answer (score 5):

MessageBox is a **class**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.aspx

`Show` is a **static** method of `MessageBox` class. You can call static methods in the format *`ClassName.MethodName`*

Another thing about `MessageBox` is that it is a `sealed` class. A [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class cannot be inherited. That means you can not derive a custom class from this class.

More info about Static classes and methods are nicely explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> I beleive for all the standard .NET class library namespaces internally create the object instances thru constructors when we refer any of the method belongs to the class. Its always object name is same as class name as its created by constructor.

Not at all. Only **static methods** can be accessed directly from the class. To call an **instance method**, you need an instance of the class (i.e. an object).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show();

System.Windows is namespace 
MessageBox is a class
Show is a static method
```

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox is a sealed class and it has a static method `ToShow()`. And to access static method you dont need to create instances.